# What's a simple way to update a Bitmap with another Bitmap given a top left corner?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm writing a Object method that is passed in a Bitmap and copies into the Object's own bitmap at the given top left corner parameter.

```
    public void updateWithSprite(int x, int y, Sprite sprite)
    {            
        //some code here. 

    }
```

What's a simple way to do this?

Comment: Why would you not just use the built-in drawing methods?  Like Graphics.DrawImage.

Comment: I'm using a pull MVC architecture - the View (the Windows form), doesn't need to know about all the individual game objects. Instead it regularly polls the game for a single bitmap to display. So it's the game that updates that bitmap independent of the view.

Comment: But yes, that could be one solution - rather than passing the view a single bitmap, to pass it a list of items with xy cordinates, and have it draw them all.

Comment: @Dan-o - Alright I see that [this here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457087.aspx) does what I want it to do. Thanks alot. 

In terms of answering this question.... I guess just leave it open until someone specifically answers this one?

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, post it as an answer, or delete the question.

Comment: @Dan-o Alright, i've modifed the question, and I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphics.DrawImage will let you do this:

```
    public void updateWithSprite(int x, int y, Sprite sprite)
    {

        Bitmap sprBitmap = sprite.getBitmap();
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.bitmap);
        g.DrawImage(sprBitmap, x, y, sprBitmap.Width, sprBitmap.Height);
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457087.aspx